# How to resolve JUnit 4 FAILED message on Initialization Error even when test case methods are all PASSED?

Tags: initialization, junit4, java

I am encountering this error in the terminal when I tried to run my test code in JUnit 4. However, my test code are all PASSED but there are FAILED errors displaying in the terminal as well which I don't understand.

NOTE: Only CallStack.java is not tested in this JUnit class

```
> Task :test FAILED

DSAQueue > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor

DSAStack > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor

EquationSolver > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

CallStack > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

DSAShufflingQueue > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor

DSACircularQueue > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor

JUnitTest > testStack PASSED

JUnitTest > testShufflingQueue PASSED

JUnitTest > testEquationSolver PASSED

JUnitTest > testCircularQueue PASSED

10 tests completed, 6 failed
```

My Test Class begins in this way.

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.*;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class JUnitTest
{
    @Test
    public void testStack()
    {
        /* test code */
    }

    @Test
    public void testShufflingQueue()
    {
        /* test code */
    }

    @Test
    public void testCircularQueue()
    {
        /* test code */
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquationSolver()
    {
        /* test code */
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors relate to other classes, not the one you shared

Comment: Errors mean that JUnit _couldn't even properly run the test_.

Comment: But I did compile and run the .java files I have in my current directory and it shows no indications of error